# how to show output text from db just in one line in django templates

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

In my Django project, I want to read some text from my PostgreSQL DB and show them just like emails that are shown in the inbox. i.e, each output shouldn't have any line-breaks(enters) or other tags.

[image]

I've wrote something like this so far:

```
<div>
     <p style="font-size: 15px;">{{ contact.message |safe|truncatewords:15|cut:"\n" }}</p>
</div>
```

I also tested `|striptags` tag instead of `|cut:"\n"`. It removes line breaks, but some other problems come with it since I'm using CKEditor **richtextfield** and the text has some markups.

how to show just 1 line of text ( up to a few words, 15 for example) without any linebreaks and HTML tags?

any help is appreciated.

Comment: In my specific case, i am using richtext with images in it. I made my own custom template tag with a bunch of regex and if/else statement to take care of several specific cases (image at the beginning of the text etc...)

Comment: please provide some example. how to make a custom tag to remove line-breaks

Comment: put a sample code as an answer with a detailed step for generating custom tags

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar thing for ckeditor generated html text using custom template tag. I re-wrote it for your purpose, but did not test it.

1. Create a `templatetags` folder in one of the apps that is listed in INSTALLED_APPS in settings file of the project. I put mine under my `custom_utilities` folder which hosts all of custom-made utilities
2. Create a blank `__init__.py` file inside the `templatetags` folder
3. Create `custom_tags.py` file inside the `templatetags` folder.
4. Inside `custom_tags.py`, create `removelinebreaks` function

```
from django import template

from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
import re
from django.utils.text import Truncator

register = template.Library()

# register filter
# is_safe is for telling Django that if a “safe” string is passed into your filter, the result will still be “safe” and if a non-safe string is passed in, Django will automatically escape it, if necessary.
@register.filter(is_safe=True)
# only accepts string as the first argument.
@stringfilter                 
def removelinebreaks(text, num):

    print('original text-----')
    print(text)

    # case insensitive matching of '&nbsp;' non-breaking space
    text= re.sub('&nbsp;', '', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE) 
    #remove space, tabs, and newlines zero or more times
    text= re.sub("<p>\s*</p>","", text, flags=re.MULTILINE) 
    # remove <br> tag.
    text= re.sub("<br>","", text)

    print('replaced text-----')
    print(text)

    # truncate the text
    return Truncator(text).chars(num) + '...'
```

5. In your template,

```
{% load custom_tags %}

{{forumpost.mytext|removelinebreaks:15|safe}}
```

6. Also make sure that **you restart the Django development server**. If the server does not restart, Django won't register the tags.

Comment: just realized that in my custom_tags.py, I missed ```from django import template``` and ```register = template.Library()``` added just now.